# No sound when using hyperlinks for videos in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I am working in GNU Emacs 27.1 (2020-08-26). My operating systems is Ubuntu 20.04 and I am using Firefox 83.0 (64-Bit) for Ubuntu.

Currently I observe the following challenge: When starting a hyperlink in org-mode written as [[Internet address][Title]] the side is correctly opening, but no tone is to hear. Copying the Internet address only and searching it in a freshly opened Firefox gives a correct result.
Who can help ?

Comment: When you follow a link in an Org mode file, where does it get opened?

Comment: Thanks for your care. I solved the problem by reloading Emacs from the Ubuntu software center. Now the hyperlink procedure works properly. I don't know how the old program was damaged. But it was the only problem I had.